# Assigning multiple tags to a resource via Azure CLI results in one big tag when using a variable

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

When creating VM via az cli (bash) with a list of tags.

First set this variable:
`tags='env=qa servertype=frontend Distinct=qa-frontend25 CI=Yes DataDog:True'`

However when running the below command in bash

```
az vm create ... --tags "${tags}"
```

It creates one long tag that has key `env` and value `qa servertype=frontend Distinct=qa-frontend25 CI=Yes DataDog=True`

From Azure CLI [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-create)

```
--tags
     Space-separated tags in 'key[=value]' format.
```

What am  missing here?

Comment: Any more question? Or if the answer if helpful you can accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to create multi-tag to one VM, you should add the parameter `--tags` like this:

```
--tags 'tag1=test1' 'tag2=test2'
```

The result like this:

[image]

It also shows in the document `az vm create` that you provide. There is a misunderstanding with you.

> --tags Space-separated tags in 'key[=value]' format. Use "" to clear existing tags.

**Update**

Yeah, you can set multi-tag in a variable and take it in the command like this:

```
tags="tag1=test1 tag2=test2"

az vm create -g resourceGroupName -n vmName --image image --tags $tags
```

It will work well and answer for @Johan, if you remove quotes it also works. It's a great question. Actually, the variable works in the CLI command like this:

```
--tags $tags -> --tags tag1=test1 tag2=test2
```

Just like using `echo $tags` in the bash.

Comment: I would still like this to use the `tags` variable like above.

Comment: What happens if you remove the quotes around the variable expansion?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in Azure CLI.

If I use --tags $tags (with $tags = "dev unit=it priority=low") I have the same issue as the OP and the output of the command output shows:

(snip)
  "tags": {
    "environment": "dev unit=it priority=low"
  },
(snip)

If I use --tags "dev unit=it priority=low" then the tags are set correctly, and the command output shows: 

(snip)
  "tags": {
    "environment": "dev",
    "priority": "low"
  },
(snip)

Comment: @Paul I think you use the CLI in Windows PowerShell or command line. So you need to follow the rule of Windows to define the variables.

Answer (score 5):

I spent 2 hours banging my head against this.
On az cli version 2.40 tags would not accept array.

```
@("tag1=value1","tag2"="value2").
```

I had to upgrade to 2.42 and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with tags="tag1=test1 tag2=test2" seems that Powershell passes this as 1 string to the az cli command, and that way az cli does not see it as "Space-separated tags" but as a single tag.
The solution that worked for me was to define $tags as an array. Then it expanded nicely for az cli to interpret. Like this:
$Tags=@("Purpose=Demo","Created=$DateShort")
az <command> --tags $Tags

Answer (score 2):

For those like me running the Azure cli in VSCode/PowerShell 7, I had to reference each tag this way, for example :

```
$tags=@('Customer=$Customer','SQLSERVER=$SQLSERVER','costcenter=''customer''')
 
az group create --name $rgName --location $Location --subscription $Subscription `
                --tags $tags[0] $tags[1] $tags[2]
```

This is assuming you know exactly how many tags you want to apply. In my case, we apply tags on all resources created by a certain script the same way, so I can use this array throughout the script.

Comment: You don't actually need to refer to each element explicitly. That scales poorly, as well. Please view my answer below. It's an extension of yours (+1 for it, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Not as fancy as you might want but here is a one that i have used before and confirm still work.

```
tags1="tag1=test1"
tags2="tag2=test2"
az vm create -n MyVm2 -g MyResourceGroup --image UbuntuLTS --tags $tags1 $tags2
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF61n.png)

[image]

Haven't found a way to groups tags into one variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in Azure CLI.
If I use --tags $tags (with $tags = "tag1=value1 tag2=value") I have the same issue as the OP and the output of the command shows:
(snip)
If I use --tags

Answer (score 0):

When I mark resources with multiple tags, I use the following array syntax.

```
$tags = @("section=hakuna", "team=matata")
az tag create --resource-id $Id --tags $tags
```

Of course, you can add the tags immediately when you create the resource as well: the same logic applies. And it's rarely that we have the ID of the resource laying around - I use that when I want to retag one.

As an extension to your request, I've started to use even neater version, by simply adding the flag `--tags` as a part of the array.

```
$tags = @("--tags", "section=hakuna", "team=matata")
az tag create --resource-id $Id $tags
```