# Tags format when creating new resource with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I'm failing to pass tags collection for new azure resource when using Azure CLI.

I have several tags validation policies, yet I have verified them via Azure Portal and the tags values are valid.

I'm using PowerShell 7.3

#### Command

```
$TAGS = "foo=X/12345/01/01 owner=joe.doe@email.com app=myapp1"
az group create `
    --name $RESOURCE_GROUP `
    --location $LOCATION `
    --query "properties.provisioningState" `
    --tags $TAGS
```

#### Validation errors

```
Type: PolicyViolation
Info: {
    "evaluationDetails": {
        "evaluatedExpressions": [
            {
                "result": "True",
                "expressionKind": "Field",
                "expression": "type",
                "path": "type",
                "expressionValue": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups",
                "targetValue": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups",
                "operator": "Equals"
            },
            {
                "result": "True",
                "expressionKind": "Field",
                "expression": "tags[foo]",
                "path": "tags[foo]",
                "expressionValue": "X/12345/01/01 owner=joe.doe@email.com app=myapp1",
                "targetValue": [
                    "X/12345/01/01",
                    ...
                ],
                "operator": "NotIn"
            }
        ]
    },
    "policyDefinitionId": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementgroups/Non-Production/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/Enforce_tag_foo_rg",
    "policyDefinitionName": "Enforce_tag_foo_rg",
    "policyDefinitionDisplayName": "Require foo tag name and correct values on resource group",
    "policyDefinitionEffect": "deny",
    "policyAssignmentId": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/Non-Production/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/Enforce_tag_foo_rg",
    "policyAssignmentName": "Enforce_tag_foo_rg",
    "policyAssignmentDisplayName": "Enforce Tag - foo on resource groups",
    "policyAssignmentScope": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/Non-Production",
    "policyAssignmentParameters": {
        "tagName": "foo",
        "tagValue": [
            "X/12345/01/01",
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Note this line

`"expressionValue": "X/12345/01/01 owner=joe.doe@email.com app=myapp1"`

This looks like invalid argument format, but `az group create -h` is clear about it.

```
Command
    az group create : Create a new resource group.

Arguments
    
    --tags                                   : Space-separated tags: key[=value] [key[=value] ...].
                                               Use "" to clear existing tags.
```

Comment: It looks like “space separated” means ```—tags “key1=value1” “key2=value2”``` rather than ```-tags “key1=value1 key2=value2”```. This question has some solutions that might help… https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723836/assigning-multiple-tags-to-a-resource-via-azure-cli-results-in-one-big-tag-when. In your case, you’re setting a tag called ```key1``` with a literal value of ```value1 key2=value2``` which violates your tag policy…

Comment: I've tried with `"` and it doesn't work. Same response.

Comment: Just to labour the point, answers in the other question suggest you need to quote each key-value pair separately and put a space between the quoted strings, rather than have a single string quoted string with multiple key-value pairs inside… i.e. ```—tags “kvp1” “kvp2”``` rather than ```—tags “kvp1 kvp2”```…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments, PowerShell is invoking this command for you:

```
az group create --name name --location location --query properties.provisioningState --tags "foo=X/12345/01/01 owner=joe.doe@email.com app=myapp1"
```

with `--tags "foo=X/12345/01/01 owner=joe.doe@email.com app=myapp1"` at the end.

The `az` command is interpretting this as a tag called `foo` with a value `X/12345/01/01 owner=joe.doe@email.com app=myapp1`, but that violates your policy so you get an error.

Note - if your policy wasn't there, `az` would quite happily create the resource group like this:

[image]

What you actually want is this:

[image]

so working backwards your `az` command needs to be

```
az group create --name name --location location --query properties.provisioningState --tags "foo=X/12345/01/01" "owner=joe.doe@email.com" "app=myapp1"
```

with `--tags "foo=X/12345/01/01" "owner=joe.doe@email.com" "app=myapp1"` at the end,

and to do that you need to use this:

```
$tags = @("foo=X/12345/01/01", "owner=joe.doe@email.com", "app=myapp1")
```

Comment: Okay, finaly I got it working. Switching from single string composition containing all tags to array of tags (just like you mentioned) did the trick.